# rails-ckeditor and thumbnails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

as i see - rails-ckeditor plugin inserting full images when user edit text. Could you tell me please - how to enable thumbnail inserting with link to original image.

Answer (score 0):

rails-ckeditor does not support thumbnails. Thumbnail support in ckeditor comes from a supplementary package called [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/). This package is currently only available for php, java, coldfusion and ASP.

This means you are out of luck and will have to create the solution yourself. You could try to use any of the standard Rails thumbnailing plugins such as Paperclip or Carrierwave; and re-write ckeditor to make use of those thumbnails instead of trying to use ckfinder. But it's not going to be an easy task.